# Laravel Eloquent Model hasMany Error "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I created an Eloquent Model :

```
class VehicleDetails extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'v_vehicle_details';

    protected $primaryKey = 'model_id';

    public function tariffs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tariffs', 'vehicle_model_id', 'model_id');
    }


}
```

The table structure for the same is v_vehicle_details is

[v_vehicle_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rexa.png)

The table structure for tariffs is

[t_tariffs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilJaq.png)

The Model is being called in controller like :

```
public function booking_view(){

        $vehicle_details = new VehicleDetails();
        return $vehicle_details->find(5)->tariffs();
}
```

What I need is to get vehicle details with all tariffs, But when I try that it throws an error **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string**. Can somebody please help, I am new to laravel.

> These are not actual tables, But views.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? What do you mean by "try that" - which line throws that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
return VehicleDetails::with('tariffs')->find(5);
```

Comment: Now the error was gone and getting the results.                                                       thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is because calling the method `->tarrifs()` will return a relationship object in this case `HasMany` this means you still have to perform the query on this object to get the results.

If you use it as a property `->tarifs` without `()` it will perform the query.
This is the same as `tarifs()->get()` just a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
public function bookingView(){
        $vehicle = VehicleDetails::with('tariffs')->find(5);       
         return view('your.view', compact('vehicle'));
}
```

The `with()` will [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the tariffs relation.

You can acess your tariffs in your view like this:

```
{{$vehicle->tariffs->anyAttributeYouWantToAccess}}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas. The find triggers the query. After that point its now a collection and you cannot run `with` on a collection. you need to swap `find` and `with` over